# How to properly import android studio project to android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have copied and pasted the entire project file from my desktop to my laptop but I am unable to import the project back into android studio on my laptop. Both are running the latest android studio version 130.737825.

I thought I would need to export the project first from my desktop and then import it on my laptop but I cannot find the export option.

The steps done to import:

1) File > import project 
2) Find and select root of specified project
3) Next > select "import project form external model" with "Gradle" selected.
4) Leave everything as default and press finish. 
5) I get the error below.

I tested the same process but with a test application that was created on the laptop and it was able to import the project perfectly fine after I closed it and removed it from the directory it was built in.

Any pointers to how I would get about this would be great. I haven't had much experience with ADT as I just jumped into Android Studio even though it's in it's infancy stage.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your this message carefully its clearly mention your **SDK directory not exist** see the second last line 
first you should configure your SDK properly then import android project.

Comment: My mistake, I missed that. Thanks